# Article search engine in php

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I am using sphinx as a search engine on my website its working perfect and I have no complain with it. The only thing it lacks is, it does not allow me to search articles whose query length is more than 15 words. I know in reality people don't use more than 3-4 words i want to use it for finding duplicate contents.

I was wondering if there is any alternative solution to sphinx. I want to cope with duplicate contents.

My main articles table is in innodb but I am also caching articles into MyISAM table as well for full text searching but when I search an article it takes ages to perform one search. Its not the query problem, i think mysql lacks the fulltext searching facility.

Thanks
Jason

Comment: What kind of query are you looking to construct that would help you find duplicate content?

Comment: FYI, "too many keywords" limitation is removed in the most recent version of sphinx

Comment: @stereofrog no its not, I am running the recent version of sphinx on windows and centos.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is an alternative.  It's based on Apache's Lucene project...

you might want to check [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) as well.

And since you're using MySQL, check it's full-text searching [MySQL Full Text Searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @stereofrog you are right. I had the old php api thats why it was not allowing me to use the full query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Zend_Search_Lucene as well: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Though it's slower than sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not helpful, but could you simply add a unique index to the MySQL field to prevent insertion of duplicates?

I have not come across any query length limitations in the Sphinx version I'm using (0.9.9), but maybe I have not tried hard enough.

Comment: I am trying to find plagiarized contents so adding unique field is not a good option. I can now insert full queries in sphinx but now it keeps crashing :(